# How Can I Resolve This PIP Installation Error on Windows?

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install `pip` on my Windows 10 machine. I downloaded it using the following command in the command line `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py`. After that, I run the following command to install `pip` `python get-pip.py`. Then, I get the following error message printed in my command prompt:

```
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-22.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)
Collecting wheel
  Using cached wheel-0.37.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
Installing collected packages: wheel, pip
  WARNING: Failed to write executable - trying to use .deleteme logic
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\Python310\\Scripts\\wheel.exe' -> 'C:\\Python310\\Scripts\\wheel.exe.deleteme'

WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
```

I tried to manually download pip at this URL `https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py`. But instead of a zip folder, I get a web page of binary data. Please, how can I resolve this error?

Comment: What's the output of `python --version`?

Comment: please run `pip install wheel`

Comment: Output of `python --version` is `3.10.2`

Comment: I just ran `pip install wheel`  and I got the following error message:

`C:\Users\IFEANYI> pip install wheel
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Python310\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'`